# When sidebar added the body content move out of the screen

Tags: html, css, sidebar

The issue is when i added the sidebar of width 230px and add the margin left to body 230px then in this case instead of the body width shrink the content move out of the screen. here is the scenario.

```
<body style="margin-left:230px;">

<aside style="position:absolute;left:0;width:230px;">content here
</aisde>

<header>
</header>

<section>
</section>

<section>
</section>
</body>
```

In this case the body content shrink but the content move outside from the body

Comment: You have something 230px wide and you are moving it 230px out to the left, of course it doesn't show.

Comment: just add position: relative in body <body style="margin-left:230px; position:relative;"> </body>

Comment: I want to shrink the body,like it happens in some dashboards,

Comment: ok you to want body in the centre and leave the blank space from right and left side?

Comment: actually i am converting in drupal when drupal admin menu added on the code it give menu 230px width and body 230px margin left but the content move away from the body. i need the content to shrink in the remaining width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello First you balise  didn't close try to correct that first .
Then using margin left is not the best solutions in every case 
For example, an alternative to margin-top:20px; margin-left:20px; would be:

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner">
</div>
</div>  
<style>
#outer { position:relative; }
#inner { position:absolute; top:20px; left:20px; }
</style>
```

and why did you use position absolute ? use position:relative